# Screenshot in android app using application context

Tags: android, kotlin, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshot in my app programmatically in Application class

```
        val mPath: String = activityContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.absolutePath.toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg"
        val view = context.window.decorView.rootView
        val bitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        view.draw(canvas)
        val imageFile = File(mPath)
```

I found this code but it only work for a single activity and I want to do this action from application to take screenshot for the foregrounded activity, also i tried  to get the current context from back stack  but i can't.
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is :

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

private Context activityContext;

...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ...
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

    this.activityContext = activity;
}


}
```